# Problem editing the init part with functions in the class

Tags: python, class

This is my current code

```
class MCP():
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        self.f = features
        self.l = labels
        self.N = epochs
        self.weights = None

    def initialize_weights(self):
        weights = np.zeros(4)
        return weights
```

I want to edit the `self.weights` with the `initalize_weights(self)` but whenever I assign something to this class and ask for weights it just tells me `None` and ignores my initialize weights:

```
x = MCP()
print(x.weights)

>> None
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't appear to be calling `initialize_weights`. Secondly, `initialize_weights` doesn't assign to `self.weights`

Comment: Because I don't see initialize weights is called any where, you need to call initialize weights either inside _init_ or after creating an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you declared a function called `initialize_weights` doesn't actually make it initialize the weights. You need to call it. Like this:

```py
class MCP():   
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        ...
        self.weights = self.initialize_weights()  # <----

    def initialize_weights(self):
        weights = np.zeros(4)
        return weights
```

Note that this misses the point of actually initializing the weights further down the program. If you want to be able to initialize weights after some calculations were made, you should alter the method to change the state instead of returning:

```py
class MCP():   
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        ...
        self.weights = None

    def initialize_weights(self):
        self.weights = np.zeros(4)
```

And now a program could look like this:

```py
x = MCP()
print(x.weights)
>> None
x.initialize_weights()
print(x.weights)
>> [0, 0, 0, 0]
# do some stuff with the object and change its weights
x.initialize_weights()
print(x.weights)
>> [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: note that `initalize_weights` is logically a static method since it does act neither on the object nor on the class.

Comment: @norok2 True. Just trying to go with the line of thought of the OP hoping to make clear his confusing. Was just about to edit in a comment about that

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def initialize_weights(self):
    self.weights = np.zeros(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the property of the object instantiated by the `class` you should use `self` (actually the first parameter of the method).

The following would show how this work:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None

    def set_a(self, value):
        self.a = value


x = foo()

print(x.a)
# None

x.set_a(10)
print(x.a)
# 10
```

---

Hence, the problem with your code are:

- `self.weights` gets assigned to `None` inside `__init__` and never touched afterwards.
- `initialize_weights()`:

  - is never called
  - even if it was called, it never modifies `self.weights`

Hence, your class could be written in a number of ways:

## Using a static method

```
import numpy as np


class MCP():
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        self.f = features
        self.l = labels
        self.N = epochs
        self.weights = self.initialize_weights()

    @staticmethod
    def initialize_weights():
        return np.zeros(4)


x = MCP()
print(x.weights)
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Note that since the method was decorated as static (with `@staticmethod`) it explicitly no longer require / use the unused `self` parameter.

## Using an initialization method

```
import numpy as np


class MCP():
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        self.f = features
        self.l = labels
        self.N = epochs
        self.weights = None
        self.initialize_weights()

    def initialize_weights(self):
        self.weights = np.zeros(4)


x = MCP()
print(x.weights)
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

---

Here, I assume that `initialize_weights()` is something you want to re-use, otherwise you could just write:

```
import numpy as np


class MCP():
    def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250):
        self.f = features
        self.l = labels
        self.N = epochs
        self.weights = np.zeros(4)


x = MCP()
print(x.weights)
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
```